# Junit Test case failure:- org.junit.ComparisonFailure

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am new on junit and mockito. in this particular example i am trying to test my HelloController method.

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {



    @RequestMapping("/hello-world")
    public String helloWorld() {
        return "Hello World";
    }

}
```

I expect this test method to succeed but unfortunately it is failing. can someone explain why this test is failing ?

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.RequestBuilder;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value=HelloWorldControllerTest.class)
public class HelloWorldControllerTest {


    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void helloWorld_basic() throws Exception {

        RequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .get("/hello-world")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(request).andReturn();
        assertEquals("Hello World",result.getResponse().getContentAsString());

    }

}
```

the failure trace says:-

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[Hello World]> but was:<[]>
```

but my controller method is clearly returning "Hello World"

Comment: The value of WebMvcTest must be the class of the controller. Not the class of the test.

Comment: ohh!! the whole day i kept on looking for mistakes on my test method. my bad. thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Voting to close for typo.